# ElasticSearch - Find all conditions of 'should' query

Tags: elasticsearch, boolean

**UPDATAD - DOC SAMPLE**

I need to create a query which search for a list of values and returns those values only if all values were found.

Otherwise, it should return empty.

For example:

Doc Example:

```
{
     "veiculo_id": "1",
     "tipo": "sensor",
     "data": "2018-03-28T08:09:51.000-0000",
     "nome": "open",
     "location": {
      "lon": -71.15812552009744,
      "lat": 41.297125384106316
       },
       "value": 0
  },

 {
     "veiculo_id": "1",
     "tipo": "sensor",
     "data": "2018-03-28T08:09:51.000-0000",
     "nome": "close",
     "location": {
      "lon": -71.15812552009744,
      "lat": 41.297125384106316
       },
       "value": 0
  }
```

*The field I'm using is 'nome'*

I'm trying to find out if a combination of events happened at that window of time.

Combination I'm looking for [open, close]

List of events `[on, on, on, on, open, off, off, close]`

How do I now if `[open, close]` event happened?

1.if I use simply should `[open, close]`, it will apply 'or', right?

2.if I use must it will apply 'and', just like I want. But ES will looking for a document that has the value `[open, close]` in the same field at same doc.

3.if I use should with `"minimum_should_match": "100%"` , it will behavior like must.

Does someone have any idea about how solve this problem?

Thanks for your support

Comment: Can you share a sample document?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question with docs examples

Comment: @valterGomes What do you mean by open, close. I see in the sample docs that values for "nome" are "position" and "vehicle_bau". Where exactly are you storing values of open and close

Comment: @Chan15 It is just example. I used open and close to simplify... sorry for confusing. Open and Close are just events

Comment: Is single query a requirement? Why not just perform two separate queries, one filtering (or must) to 'open', one to 'close', and check if both return > 0 documents?

Comment: @Miek The goal here is to realize if the two events happened in a time window. I would like to let for ES decide if it happened or not., instead of, decide it on the code in client side